# Popup menu not appearing in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show a popup menu when the user right clicks on a button.

CSS:

```
#popup-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

In HTML body of popup.html (mark up for the Chrome Extension):

```
<button id="mybutton" type="button">Right Click Me!</button>
<div id="popup-menu">
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="test1" src="images/image1.png"></td>
                <td>Test Item 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="test2" src="images/image2.png"></td>
                <td>Test Item 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function tryIt(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.which == 3) {
    var popup = document.getElementById('popup-menu');
    popup.classList.toggle('show');
  } else alert('Something else');
}
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', tryIt);
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('contextmenu', tryIt);
```

The right click is working but the popup menu does not appear. I put "contextMenus" in the permissions of the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

any reason why you wrote this in this way? `getEltById` is a not an existing method.

```js
getEltById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', tryIt);
getEltById('mybutton').addEventListener('contextmenu', tryIt);
```

The correct way to write it is:

```js
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', tryIt);
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('contextmenu', tryIt);
```

Comment: Sorry, getEltById is just a shortcut function that I wrote. Anyway I removed it from my question.